# Support for RGBa in IE9+

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, rgb, rgba

How can I adjust the RGBa to work in IE9+ ?

Here is the code I'm using for IE:

```
         background:none;
    -ms-filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#500000ff,endColorstr=#500000ff);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#500000ff,endColorstr=#500000ff);
    zoom: 1;
```

PS. In IE8 works just fine

Comment: `-ms-filter` takes a string. Put quotes around that whole value.

Comment: IE9+ generally supports RGBa, but only in standards mode. As [pointed out here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515551/rgba-not-working-in-ie9) you may have to check your doctype for it to work properly.

Comment: I've tried that but still doesn't work

Comment: filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */

this is working in ie9.