# CSS properties fail to load for some pages

Tags: css, rgba

First of all, let me mention how incredibly difficult it is to work with IE.

I have a single CSS stylesheet that is being used with three pages: Login, Forgot Password and Change Password pages. One of the div CSS properties, RGBA to be more specific, loads correctly for Login page, but fails for other two. When you examine the element it is simply not there. It is not being overridden by anything, it is just not there. Even in the CSS tab it does not show up in the class where it is declared.

I tried clearing browser's cache and basically resetting it, still nothing. Any ideas? Works as expected in Chrome.

Here is the div tag and CSS block in question:

```
<div class="preLogin" style="height: 385px;">

div.preLogin
{
    padding: 75px 0px 0px 75px;
    height: 350px;
    width:  265px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-212px;
    margin-top: -66px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /*background-color: rgba(224, 239, 246, 0.5); */
    background-color: rgba(127, 255, 212, 0.1); 
}
```

EDIT: Not even using inline style does anything. I am using IE9 and it has to work there.

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: Yes, please share the HTML and CSS code you are using (or setup a fiddle)

Comment: are you sure you have correctly **linked** your css stylesheet with all the pages where you are using it?

Comment: Your IE isn't running in compatibility mode is it? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515551/rgba-not-working-in-ie9

Comment: Are you sure you have nothing else overriding it as it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/9N5kZ/1/

Comment: Albion, it is applying other properties from that stylesheet correctly, just that rgba property is not being used in other two pages.

Comment: LDJ, compatability mode is off. Pete, wouldn't it be crossed out if it were overriden? In this case it does not show up at all.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by commenting out the following line in the header for those two pages:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

I guess I had compatibility mode turned on after all.